# Visual Studio enable "Ctrl + Click"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How do you enable the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + `Click` option. For example if you make a new object from a class and you <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + `Click` on the class name you go to that class, or the same with a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click on the class name or whatever and press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Ok that works alos, but i can ctrl + click in visual studio 2012 and not in 2013.

Comment: Is it possible to switch back ? If yes, Whats the shortcut key ?

Comment: this is so annoying, ctrl is super easy to find without looking, how are you finding f12? and what for, the ctrl + mouse don do anything in most cases

Answer (score 17):

This setting is controlled through [Visual Studio - Go To Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2022#ctrl-click-go-to-definition):

1. **Tools**->**Options**
2. **Text Editor** category
3. **General** subcategory
4. Check (or uncheck) **Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition**

[image: Options > Text Editor > General > Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition]